# LibreOffice Writer in Windows missed images from Linux

Tags: linux, debian, openoffice, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I'm using LibreOffice Writer in Linux to edit a document with images.

But when I move file created under Linux to Windows not show images inside the document.

**My LibreOffice version:**

> LibreOffice  5.0.4.2 (Debian 8.3)
>
> LibreOffice 5.0.0.5 (Windwos 8)

See bellow my capture in Windows platform:

[Image1 Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI71Z.png)

[Image4 Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOOy3.png)

Comment: The most probable reason is that the image link is addressed differently in the two operation systems.  If you right-click on the image, you will see an option `Picture...` or `Image...`, and the properties window which appears when you click it will have a `Picture` or `Image` tab, where you can see the file name it is trying to use. Put the image on a shared drive and use its URI reference: in this way it will be accessible from both systems.

Comment: First I think that, but the image not have link. The image is inside of the document. I forget write, that not are all image missed. Only some images are missed...

Comment: Is `Edit -> Links` greyed out?  Also what is the format of the image?  For example .png or .jpg.

Comment: Edit -> is gray (inactive). The image are eps. But when I copy and paste image inside document or used Insert -> Image the image should be inserted inside the document.

Comment: EPS files have limited portability, according to the second-last paragraph of the Preview section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript). Note that they should be printable, even though you can't see them in preview. Are the missing images all EPS files, and the others in another format?

Comment: Appear that Windows not have support for eps images. png images aren't missed. But I choose eps because when png resize losse images quality.